# Unnecessary ASM code

Tags: c, assembly, arm, keil

I'm preparing to optimize some code for cortex-m4 (educationally only) so I write simple inline function like this:

```
inline int8_t recalculate_val(uint16_t ADC_val){
int16_t value;
value += fuzzywynik1 + ADC_val;
return value;
}
```

Now when I'm previewing asm code I can see plenty of line that I couldn't understand:

```
0x08002618 F44F7081  MOV           r0,#0x102
0x0800261C E04A      B             0x080026B4
0x0800261E E04C      B             0x080026BA
0x08002620 006A      DCW           0x006A
0x08002622 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002624 0024      DCW           0x0024
0x08002626 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002628 0C2C      DCW           0x0C2C
0x0800262A 4000      DCW           0x4000
0x0800262C 0004      DCW           0x0004
0x0800262E 0040      DCW           0x0040
0x08002630 0800      DCW           0x0800
0x08002632 4002      DCW           0x4002
0x08002634 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002636 4001      DCW           0x4001
0x08002638 00BC      DCW           0x00BC
0x0800263A 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x0800263C 6410      DCW           0x6410
0x0800263E 4002      DCW           0x4002
0x08002640 0C00      DCW           0x0C00
0x08002642 4002      DCW           0x4002
0x08002644 00AC      DCW           0x00AC
0x08002646 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002648 0028      DCW           0x0028
0x0800264A 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x0800264C ED18      DCW           0xED18
0x0800264E E000      DCW           0xE000
0x08002650 E400      DCW           0xE400
0x08002652 E000      DCW           0xE000
0x08002654 680D      DCW           0x680D
0x08002656 3B53      DCW           0x3B53
0x08002658 0054      DCW           0x0054
0x0800265A 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x0800265C 008C      DCW           0x008C
0x0800265E 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002660 3830      DCW           0x3830
0x08002662 4002      DCW           0x4002
0x08002664 1000      DCW           0x1000
0x08002666 4002      DCW           0x4002
0x08002668 6425      DCW           0x6425
0x0800266A 0000      DCW           0x0000
0x0800266C 003C      DCW           0x003C
0x0800266E 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002670 0090      DCW           0x0090
0x08002672 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002674 0046      DCW           0x0046
0x08002676 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002678 6F50      DCW           0x6F50
0x0800267A 797A      DCW           0x797A
0x0800267C 6A63      DCW           0x6A63
0x0800267E 3A61      DCW           0x3A61
0x08002680 2520      DCW           0x2520
0x08002682 0073      DCW           0x0073
0x08002684 6E45      DCW           0x6E45
0x08002686 6F6B      DCW           0x6F6B
0x08002688 6564      DCW           0x6564
0x0800268A 3A72      DCW           0x3A72
0x0800268C 2520      DCW           0x2520
0x0800268E 0073      DCW           0x0073
0x08002690 0038      DCW           0x0038
0x08002692 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002694 0050      DCW           0x0050
0x08002696 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x08002698 006C      DCW           0x006C
0x0800269A 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x0800269C 006F      DCW           0x006F
0x0800269E 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x080026A0 0072      DCW           0x0072
0x080026A2 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x080026A4 0075      DCW           0x0075
0x080026A6 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x080026A8 0078      DCW           0x0078
0x080026AA 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x080026AC 007B      DCW           0x007B
0x080026AE 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x080026B0 0068      DCW           0x0068
0x080026B2 2000      DCW           0x2000
0x080026B4 F7FFFDB8  BL.W          recalculate_val (0x08002228)
```

Can someone explain me what for  B, DCW (why so many?) and BL.W instruction are used?

Comment: You know that your function is _REALLY_ broken? Adding to an uninitialized variable doesn't seem like a good idea... As for your question, the code you show is most likely some array in memory, probably with registers or memory locations.

Comment: you are not showing us enough of your program, this asm and the C code dont have anything to do with each other for example.

Answer (score 2):

The `B` instructions are unconditional branches and seem to be branching to the call of your `recalculate_val` routine. The `BL` instruction is a so-called "branch with link" and is used for calling functions so that the instruction pointer can return to the instruction following the `BL` after the function has returned.

The `DCW` directives define global halfwords of memory. You have to look for any definitions of global initialised data that might correspond to these. They are not really instructions and you can see that the left-hand side (the way they are encoded) is the same as the right-hand side (the data they define).

Anyway, the piece of code you have shown doesn't include the definition of the `recalculate_val` routine. You have to look what's at the address `0x08002228` (that's where the `BL` jumps). Also, the compiler doesn't seem to honour the `inline` specifier.

Answer (score 2):

> for B, DCW (why so many?) and BL.W instruction

`B` is unconditional jump, `BL` is a function call (jump with link).

The `DCW`s are constants. Look at them more closely:

```
0x08002620 006A      DCW           0x006A
0x08002622 2000      DCW           0x2000
```

This is `0x2000006A`, most likely an address of a variable in RAM.

```
0x08002624 0024      DCW           0x0024
0x08002626 2000      DCW           0x2000
```

Thats `0x20000024`, another RAM address.

```
0x08002628 0C2C      DCW           0x0C2C
0x0800262A 4000      DCW           0x4000
```

This `0x40000C2C` is in peripherial space - most likely a register address.

The reason for them is that you cannot encode most 32 bit values directly in Thumb2 instructions. One workaround is using a table like above with the instruction
`LDR Rx, [PC + y]` which loads the corresponding table value into the target register.

You should find matching `LDR` instructions in the disassembly above or below the code shown.

But this `LDR` instruction has a limited range - especially when encoded as 16 Bit. Thats why a complier may insert a table in the middle of some code and use `B` instructions to jump around it.